# How to count the number of threads in every process in Windows using MFC

Tags: windows, winapi, process, mfc

I want to build a task manager like application using MFC. I have already succeeded in enumerating the various processes running currently their PIDs and memory usage.

My problem is that i also want to obtain the number of threads each process has running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that (and many more related things) with the [Tool helper library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681926%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (win32) by taking a process [snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682489%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) then walking [`Thread32First/Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686728%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Although i dont need to walk through the threads, the PROCESSENTRY32 structure contains a filed for the number of threads. I can simply retrieve that value and my job will be done.